# Player constantly has a velocity of -7 on Y axis

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I recently started making a new project and I'm still a beginner at coding. But recently I've made a jumping animation, and a falling animation. I've implemented those two things, and I made it so that if the Player has a velocity < 0 then activate falling anim. But, for some reason every time I press play the Player always has a velocity of -7 on the Y axis and never 0. Here's the code:

```
void OnMove()
{
    Vector2 vec = actions.Movement.Move.ReadValue<Vector2>();

    playerVelocity = new Vector2 (vec.x * speed, rb2d.velocity.y);
    rb2d.velocity = playerVelocity;
}

void OnJump()
    {
        isGrounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, checkRadius, whatIsGround);

        if(isGrounded)
        {
            animator.SetBool("isFalling", false);
        }

        if(isGrounded && actions.Movement.Jump.GetButtonDown())
        {
            isJumping = true;
            jumpTimeCounter = jumpTime;
            rb2d.velocity += new Vector2 (0f, jumpForce);        
        }

        if(actions.Movement.Jump.GetButton() && isJumping == true)
        {
            animator.ResetTrigger("hasJumped");
            animator.SetBool("isFalling", false);
            animator.SetTrigger("hasJumped");

            if (jumpTimeCounter > 0)
            {
                rb2d.velocity = new Vector2 (0f, jumpForce);
                jumpTimeCounter -= Time.deltaTime;
                animator.SetTrigger("hasJumped");
            }
            else
            {
                isJumping = false;
                animator.SetBool("isFalling", false);
                animator.ResetTrigger("hasJumped");
            }
        }

        if(rb2d.velocity.y < 0)
        {
            animator.SetBool("isFalling", true);
        }
    }
```

Here's the inspector:

[image: screenshot]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you send screenshots of the inspector and the game view?

Comment: Can you make sure that jumpForce is positive?

Comment: @IamHoussam Yeah, it is possitive. If by possitive you mean just simply putting a default value of 5 for the jump force. Because when I jump it does add velocity on the Y.